# VBA/ACCESS: How to quickly delete plenty records from table?

Tags: sql, vba, recordset

I desperately try to delete a huge amount of records from a table in an access database (*.accdb) within an acceptable time.

More specific: I have a collection of integer IDs (ca. 50.000) whose corresponding records are supposed to be deleted from a table (ca. 300.000 rows).

Using a "for each x in collection" + "db.execute(SQL delete command)" approach takes ages.

Is there any other solution I could try?

Many thanks in advance and regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

Use something like `DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (...)` and fill the set for the IN part as appropriate, e.g. `id IN (5, 6, 12)`.

Edit: for practical reasons, you could limit the amount of IDs in the IN set to, say, 1000. This would still reduce your number of queries by a large factor.

Comment: If they're *continuous* `BETWWEN` may be more efficient. That's a big *if* though.